# Machine learning on Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I am new to neural networks and I am trying to implement self driving on an RC car. I was planning on using a CNN for image recognition (Correct me if I am wrong which I most likely am).

I was wondering if it was possible to run image recognition on a cheaper processor rather than a full single board computer.

P.S I found the following module, I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with it.

https://www.seeedstudio.com/Sipeed-MAIX-I-module-w-o-WiFi-1st-RISC-V-64-AI-Module-K210-inside-p-3210.html

Comment: People have done machine vision stuff on microcontrollers, but it depends on what you want to do and having the right camera goes a long way to make it more feasible on a microcontroller (less pixels, monochrome, etc). I've not heard of neural nets on microcontrollers. I don't think they are powerful enough. About your processor (I would not call that a microcontroller. It looks really full-blown), make sure check the development tools for it. That's more important than the actual processor.

Comment: It all depends on the parcours. A one-line parcours can be followed by something as simple as two photodiodes and no AI at all.

Comment: @DKNguyen Acutually, STM already provides a whole [framework](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/stm32-ann.html) for this, as well as bugging developers with offers of training seminars on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A 0.23 TOPs solution like you showed will have an inference latency of multiple hundreds of ms (a couple of frames per second.) This might be acceptable for a slow-moving RC car. Something faster will want higher throughput / lower latency.

There are AI compute stick accelerator solutions that can work with a microcontroller over USB. Well-known ones include Google Coral, Intel / Movidius Myriad X. Less well known is the Gyrfalcon 5801, which is the same chip as in the new LG Q70 phone.

These solutions will have throughputs in the 10 - 50 fps range, enough to cover  single camera with reasonably low latency.

Might as well add this one too: Solidrun offers a System-on-Module with an i.MX8 and 16.8 TOPs AI coprocessor. This will be able to handle multiple cameras at low latency. Frame rates in the multiple hundreds of FPS. More here: https://www.solid-run.com/nxp-family/imx8m-mini-som/

Comment: About the last module, something like that would be a little pricey (around $100), the again, I am assuming there will be some considerable expense when looking for something that could support a CNN.

Comment: About the accelerators, are you saying I could port a CNN onto them and then interface it with a microcontroller through USB?

Comment: Yes. The toolcchain varies, but most support Pytorch, Caffe, and Tensorflow. Fair warning: you will need to do training on a GPU.