# How does a doorbell work?

Tags: low-power

I'm trying to make my own smart doorbell with the same wiring of our current doorbell, so I'm investigating how the bell work snow. I know how part of the bell gong works, but how does the bell button itself work (with light inside of it.) The gong is the Honeywell D117 and is connected like the picture. The button of the doorbell is the [Nico 12V~1A (include light)](https://www.niko.eu/en/products/door-communication/bell-push-buttons/bell-push-button-productmodel-niko-17a6c8e3-fd43-5340-8166-764612bf417f/05-540).

[image]

Is it correct that the light is in parallel with the switch and when pressing the button of the doorbell it closes the switch and closes the system? Isn't this a short circuit when you do this without any resistor in the circuit?

My new smart doorbell will be made with a Raspberry Pi so I need DC voltage for it. Would it work to add a transformer in parallel with a switch to replace the current button to a new system?

Comment: what kind of light is it?

Comment: It a simple led light in the doorbell button.

Comment: Added also a link to the Niko doorbell button in the question.

Comment: Which parts of the original doorbell system are you keeping?

Comment: Only the gong. I just want to replace the Niko button to my own creation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**How does a doorbell work?**

The bell transformer supplies AC voltage, typically 16V but ranging from 10 to 24V, which is wired in series through the doorbell coil and the push button switch. When you press the button its contacts close, completing the circuit. Current flows through the coil, which pulls in the bell striker and rings the first 'ding' bell tone. Release the switch, a spring pushes the bell striker back where it strikes the 'dong' tone.

How much current? The doorbell coil has some DC resistance as well as reactance, both of which limit the current when the switch is closed: it doesn’t ‘dead short’. The coil impedance is in the 100-200 ohm range, so when it's energized at 16V the current is in the 80-160mA range.

The pushbutton light is wired across the switch contacts. Without the button pressed the light draws a small current (about 10mA) through the bell coil, enough to light the light but not enough to pull in the bell striker. This is an important detail: the light is a small, high-resistance bulb, its current draw set up to give a dim illumination without triggering the bell. Of course the light goes off while you're pressing the button.

**How do I replace the bell with an R.pi?**

If your intention is to replace the bell itself with your R.pi, then you need to do two things:

- Make the R.pi 5V DC from the bell transformer AC.

Such converters are available and inexpensive. Example: [https://www.amazon.com/SMAKN%C2%AE-Converter-Voltage-Supply-Waterproof/dp/B00RE6QN4U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RE6QN4U)

- Provide enough voltage to the switch to light the light, while sensing its closure with the R.pi

You still need a high enough voltage to light the switch light, so running it directly with R.pi 5V won't work: it'll be way too dim.

Instead, get a 12V relay, run the 16VAC through the relay coil to the switch wire. (This relay would do nicely: https://www.grainger.com/product/OMRON-General-Purpose-Relay-6C874) The relay will stay normally open, and will close when the button is pressed. If the relay closes because of the lamp alone, add a shunt resistance across the coil.

Then, monitor the relay contacts with the R.pi: when the button is pressed the relay should close.

Here's the general scheme:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZFbEM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

You've stated your intention to replace the doorbell button with R.pi. Ok, let's talk about that.

**How does a ‘Ring’ doorbell work?**

To use the existing transformer and bell, with only the switch being changed out, requires some careful design. The 'Ring' doorbell unit satisfies this requirement, needing only the switch wire connections that come to the doorbell button + light to do its thing. How? tl; dr: It's a complicated beast with its own battery and very tight power management.

Like that switch light, Ring uses only a small amount of this through-the-bell current. It can do this because Ring spends most of its time asleep in a very low-power mode. During sleep time, the small standby current from the bell coil charges an internal battery inside the unit and illuminates the button light.

Ring wakes up when it detects motion from a passive IR sensor array on the front of the unit. Once awakened, its camera, main processor and wifi turn on and do their thing, drawing current from its battery.

When the Ring button is pressed, it shorts out the switch wires, ringing the physical bell, while it continues to supply its own power from its battery.

To do all this, the Ring includes a bridge rectifier and voltage / charge controller that not only maintains the battery, but also limits the current draw to a level below which the bell will strike, just like that dim bulb in the mechanical switch button.

That’s the key to how it works: low standby draw charges a battery while the Ring is asleep, and the battery supplies power when it wakes up.

**How do I replace the doorbell button with R.pi?**

If your intention is to use the existing bell, transformer and wire pair for your own R.pi project, you have two choices:

- (1) Do the same low-standby magic as Ring, using a battery
  - or -
- (2) Run a separate power pair to the R.pi

If you choose option (1), and you have some design skills, that would be a really neat project ([though I'd choose ESP32](https://hackaday.com/2020/12/22/diy-esp32-video-doorbell-locks-out-big-brother/) rather than R.pi.) That said, note that even Ring draws too much standby current for some bells, enough current to pull in the bell striker. To overcome this, Ring sells an accessory that shunts some current around the bell coil to supply the extra current. You could use this technique also.

On the other hand, if you don't want to take on that battery-power design challenge, and instead power the R.pi all the time with up to 5W, then option (2), running a second low-voltage AC pair directly from the transformer to a low-voltage AC to 5VDC converter would be more doable. Then, use a small relay controlled by an R.pi GPIO to emulate the button press and ring the bell.

Comment: My intention was to fully replace the bell button with a Raspberry pi and the button on the pi.

Comment: The challenge you face is that it’s very hard to control how much power the R.pi is using at any given moment, and it uses a lot of peak power (5W), much more than Ring does. This makes drawing current through the bell coil impractical. I’d run the second pair of power wires instead - much easier. The Ring is quite complicated yet much lower power than R.pi.

Comment: I wass thinking of creating a secondarry circuit for only powering the pi and use a relay to close the circuit of the gong. ESP32 was also a good idea but I want to use TensorFlow to add some nice features.

Comment: Do you intend to do AI inferencing on the Pi itself, or use an accelerator?

Comment: Probably with an accelerator.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483191/machine-learning-on-microcontroller

Comment: And also: http://www.orangepi.org/Orange%20Pi%204B/

Comment: Unfortunately Ring didn't control the current well enough. A couple weeks after installing it, I was awakened each night by a buzzing sound. I eventually discovered it was the doorbell solenoid.  At night, when it was cold, and after the batteries lost that new battery smell, the Ring would decide to top off the charge for an hour or two, starting about 1 am. This allowed enough current to flow that the solenoid coil would buzz. The support folks declared the unit defective, but the replacement did the same thing (after a couple weeks).

Comment: Hey @hacktastical, I appreciate your contribution. I followed your diagram but incorporated a smart doorbell button by adding a "power kit" in parallel to R2 and RLY1. Everything functioned correctly until I used the doorbell button. At that point, the relay began to continuously "ring" and failed to return to its idle state—essentially, the power kit didn't "reset". Any ideas on what might be causing this issue? Here's a video illustrating the problem: https://static.marat.to/wemo.mp4

The components are: 200 ohm shunt, Omron MY24AC relay, Belkin Wemo Doorbell powerkit.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of bell works by using a solenoid to move a striker, striking the right bar when power is applied, then it is returned by a spring and strikes the right bar when power is removed (assuming it sounds "ding-dong", not "dong-ding").

The solenoid is basically a coil, which has a very low DC resistance, but enough AC impedance (inductance in this case) that it works fine with the transformed 50/60 Hz AC power.

I would, as you suggest, assume that the light is connected in parallel with the switch, but draws a low enough current to not energize the solenoid and move the striker.

For powering this with DC, I would add a series resistance *if needed** (with a high-enough power rating) of an appropriate value. What this value is would depend on the resistance of the coil, and how much current it needs. This could be calculated if the required information is available, but it would probably be simpler to figure it out by trial and error.

* The manual [here](https://www.enummerbanken.se/UserContent/ArticleDocs/MAN/MAN_11995_5336133.pdf) seems to indicate that it can be powered with four 1.5V cells directly, so it is probably possible to power this from 5-6V DC. Just make sure you aren't using the Raspberry PI GPIOs directly, as they are most likely not able to deliver enough current.

Comment: I will use the Zero2Go omni board to power the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: But do I need some more cabled when replacing the full flow to DC? Because the Pi need normally more then 1A to be powered one (with some hats). And the gong can only handle 1A. One cable to the button itself is then the grond and the other the 5V, for powering the gong itself I need a third wire to give the signal?

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple designs - ding-dong and Drrrrrrrrng.

**Ding-dong** design is simpler. There is a solenoid that when energized (button pressed) attracts the spring-loaded hammer on ellastic lever. As the hammer's lever hits the limit, the head srings forward and hits the *Ding* bell.
As the solenoid is de-energised (button released) the spring pushes the hammer back. The head springs a little and hit the *Dong* bell.

**Drrrrrrrrrng** design is almost the same with just one little feature built in - the interrupter.
When the button is pressed, the solenoid is energised, hammer attracted and it hits the bell. At the same time, the hammer discontinues the circuit, so the spring pulls the hammer back in home position. There the hammer swithces the circuit back on and solenoid is re-energised...
It is so fast that the bell does not have time to do *Ding*. The *rrrrr* is the hamer hitting the bell over and over like a woodpecker hits a branch to hunt a worm.
It can be single-bell *Drrrrring* or double-bell *Drrrrrong* design.

If you hold the *Ding-Dong* for too long it is a short-circuit. When the voltage is low enough, the resistances among the circuit are high enough to supperss excessive currents; in other word all the wires are somewhat current-limiting resistors.

For the smart design using Arduino or any other board, proper voltage scaling is the key. For the light, you can use three-wires design or two-wires design.

Four wires: PWR,GND,signal+,signal-. The "simplest" design. PWR and GND to power the LED, signals to control the arduino.
Three wires: PWR,GND,signal. Connect the LED and protective resistor to PWR and GND. Connect the switch to PWR and signal. 
Two wires: PWR and GND. Connect the LED and resistor in series and the switch parallel to PWR and GND. The switch will bypass the LED when pressed. If you add another resistor to limit the current and detect the current increase, you can get the information as well.

The two-wire design can trigget three states: No current - fault, level 1 - off, level 2 - on.